# How to manually trigger a PostBackOnFilter in a Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik radgrid which contains some telerik:GridBoundColumns. Until now all of them had their AutoPostBackOnFilter value set to true. This made a filter apply whenever I hit enter while inside in one of the filterboxes or if I simply left the focus of the given filter. I want to remove this functionality. So I set AutoPostBackOnFilter to "false".

If I now create a custom button on the page is there a way to trigger this same PostBack via my button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is going to vary depending on the version of Telerik that you are using; howerver, in general, telerik dumps out standard HTML, so if tou are going to be submitting form data a plain old submit should work. Also Telerik does use Ajax to handle specialized events. Here is an example:

Aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clientClick() {
            var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>");
            ajaxManager.ajaxRequest("client");
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnServer" runat="server" Text="Make server AjaxRequest" OnClick="btnServer_Click" />
    <input id="btnClient" type="button" value="Make client AjaxRequest" onclick="clientClick();" />
</div>
</form>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btnServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadAjaxManager1.RaisePostBackEvent("server");
}
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    RadAjaxManager1.Alert("AjaxRequest raised from the " + e.Argument);
}
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajax/server-side-programming/events/onajaxrequest

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/control-lifecycle/how-to-fire-command-events

Comment: What do you mean by "a plain old submit should work"?

Comment: <input type="Submit" Text="Submit" />

Comment: Again the post back is submitting an HTML form, so if all you need is the form data, then the submit should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not apply the filter. Maybe this only works while the AutoPostBackOnFilter is set to true?

Comment: I added another link to the answer.   Using the ajax you can fire specific events including the Filter event.